# Is it possible to put buttons under each element in a grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to make a grid with items/pizza toppings to order, and I would like an "Add to cart" button under each item in the grid. How would I go about doing that?

So far I've tried simply putting a button with a line break under an element but as assumed, that didn't work.

Here is the relevant code I have in the body:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;
  grid-row-gap: 30px;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
}

.item {
  background: firebrick;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item:nth-child(even) {
  background: rgb(139, 19, 19);
}

.add {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

button {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

#container {
  background-color: maroon;
  width: 1500px;
  height: 1200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style: double;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">
    <h1> Pizza Planet </h1>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <h2>Select your items:</h2>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="item">1</div>
      <div class="add"><button>Add To Cart</button></div>
      <div class="item">2</div>
      <div class="item">3</div>
      <div class="item">4</div>
      <div class="item">5</div>
      <div class="item">6</div>
      <div class="item">7</div>
      <div class="item">8</div>
      <div class="item">9</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All that does is make a huge gap for another cell on the grid with a tiny add to cart button on there. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Have you tried (for example)  `<div class="item">1 <div class="add"><button>Add To Cart</button></div></div>`?

Comment: I hadn't, so I just did now. It looks better but still not quite what I was looking to do. I have a 30px gap between rows, and was hoping to put the button below each cell in that gap if possible. Also just realized I left out my CSS code so I will edit the post nop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach might be to use [CSS grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) to achieve what you require. A simple grid layout for what you describe above could be done like this:

```css
.item img {
  width:100%;
  /* Causes the button to sit below the img */
  display:block;
}

.item button {
  width:100%;
}

.grid {
  /* Specifies css grid to be used */
  display:grid; 
  /* Specifies the number of columns and sizes in the grid */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  /* Specifies spacing between grid cells */
  grid-gap:1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://wallpapersdsc.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Pizza_Images12.jpg" />
    <button>Order</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://wallpapersdsc.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Pizza_Images12.jpg" />
    <button>Order</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://wallpapersdsc.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Pizza_Images12.jpg" />
    <button>Order</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://wallpapersdsc.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Pizza_Images12.jpg" />
    <button>Order</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that's perfect! I was trying to use CSS Grid but I didn't know how to get the button to sit below the menu item. So it's just that display:block; line that makes that happen?

Comment: @SaucedCaveman you're welcome! Yes, applying `display:block` to the `<img/>` element will put the `<button>` on a new line